# Remove HTML tags for creating contextual links

Tags: regex, tridion, tridion-2011

I have written a function in ASP.NET to create the contextual links. It takes the data from the description field of a component in Tridion. I am using 'RenderComponentField' to pick the data from the description field which picks up the complete source of the data with all the HTML tags.

The code is working fine. However, it fails at times when it gets the 'text' for which we want to make the contextual link in some HTML tags like anchor tag etc. It picks the text from the HTML tag and create the link there itself which breaks the HTML.

Just like, we want to create the contextual link for the text 'dummy' and we have an anchor link in our HTML as

```
<a href="http://www.dummy.com">Dummy</a>
```

As soon as it finds the text dummy in the 'href', it creates the link then and there which breaks the HTML.

Please provide a resolution for this. Probably, a regular expressions that bypasses the HTML tags or anything of that sort.

Cheers,
Anubhav

Comment: Hi, i'm afraid this makes very little sense, perhaps you could provide your code and some more details about the schema you're using, plus what 'tridion' gives you, and what you'd like to see published

Comment: @johnwinter Made some minor changes in the text above. Hope that would  help you understand the issue clearly. Regards, Anubhav

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get the problem, what do you mean with "contextual links". You said you pick the data from the "Description" field, what type of field is it? (I assume it is an RTF, because you say "it picks up the complete source of the data with all the HTML tags")

Can you maybe post what an example of the html you are expecting to get, and what you actually get?

Comment: Hi, The concept of contextual link is pretty simple. You have a keyword say 'abc'. You want to convert that into a URL everytime you find it on a piece of text on your website. You are right. The text I am talking about here is in Rich text format. What I am trying to say is that my code picks the source of the text and if it finds the keyword anywhere in the html, it creates a link there itself and breaks the HTML. I have edited my question asked above. Hope that would help you understand the problem statement. Regards, Anubhav

Comment: Still not clear, can you post the HTML output before @@RenderComponentField()@@ gets executed, the error message you get in Template Builder (or the publisher) and the HTML Output you expect afterwards? Also, what you wrote is a Source Function? or a c# template Building Block?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, you may use it like

```
 search = "(dummy)";
    replace = "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>"; 
     Regex.Replace(stringToSearch, search, replace);
```

but not sure about your requirement so can't suggest where to use above code.